# How to move my database calls from the Web API to Class Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, class-library

I have Web Api that have this call:

```
[HttpGet("getLocation")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation([FromQuery] int id)
{
    var ConnectionString = new ConnectionStringsOptions();
    _Configuration.GetSection(ConnectionStringsOptions.ConnectionStrings).Bind(ConnectionString);
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnectionString))
    {
        var _id = new
        {
            ID = id
        };
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fLocationFilter](@ID)";
        var _Location = await cnn.QueryAsync<Location>(sql, _id);
        return Ok(_Location);
    }
}
```

I want to move that call from the API to my class library to be like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation([FromQuery] int id)
{
    var _location= Mylibrery.getCall(string connectionString ,int id);
    return Ok(_location);
}
```

Can I make calls without using tasks? And is that gonna affect the performance

I'm using for class library .NET Core 5 and ASP.NET Core 5.
Update: the main question is how I can get the actionResult passed from the class library to the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside your library may look something like this:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Repository(IConfiguration configuration /* ILogger, etc */)
    {
        _connectionString = /* get connection string from configuration */
    }

    public async Task<Location> GetLocation(int id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var _id = new { ID = id };
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fLocationFilter](@ID)";
            var location = await cnn.QueryAsync<Location>(sql, _id);
            return location;
        }
    }
}
```

Its use in the controller will look something like this:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public SomeController(IRepository repository /* ILogger, etc */)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet("getLocation")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocation([FromQuery] int id)
    {
        var location = await _repository.GetLocation(id);
        return Ok(location);
    }
}
```

You should definitely use tasks, or rather, asynchronous code, if you want to get high overall performance of your service.

Comment: it's finely working thank you! , I just had to add to my ConfigureServices() this line of code services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();... I'm not familiar with dependency injection or any design patterns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0